# What is difference between "Merge branch 'develop' into feature/tmp" and "Merge branch 'develop' of https://github.com/~ into feature/tmp"?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I saw two merge commit message `Merge branch 'develop' into feature/tmp` and `Merge branch 'develop' of https://github.com/~ into feature/tmp`. What is difference between them?

Comment: Commit messages are just free text. Are they're messages generated by GitHub interface?

Comment: Probably the difference is merging a _local_ branch into feature/tmp or merging a _remote_ branch and/or one being a human doing it manually and another being automatically triggered on github by pressing a 'merge' button. How are those merges being generated?  **Please edit the question to clarify**.

Comment: @AD7six 
I don't know how to make this("Merge branch 'develop' into feature/tmp") message. Before push my code to github, I always do `$git pull origin develop` first, and It makes this("Merge branch 'develop' of https://github.com/~ into feature/tmp".) message.

Comment: @AD7six If I want to make this("Merge branch 'develop' into feature/tmp") message, 1. pull origin/develop to local/develop 2. pull local/develop to local/feature/tmp is right???

Comment: @miro ring : the first message is the default message you will get if you run (locally) `git merge develop` from `feature/tmp`. This action is also part of `git pull origin develop` (`git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` followed by `git merge`).

Comment: @miroring please edit the question to show what you are doing (and generally any time clarification is requested in a comment) - do not write comments.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said in comments, the message you see here is just text.  Anyone can create any text they like.  But these two messages are the *default* text for certain Git commands.  To understand this, you must understand Git and commits.

A Git repository consists of two databases:

- One database holds commits, and other internal Git objects.
- The other database holds names: branch names, tag names, and other names.  These names help you (and Git) find the *commits* you care about.

All Git internal objects are strictly read-only, and for the most part, the object database is something you only ever *add* to.  That's how Git can get any of your previous versions back: the previous versions are in previous commits.  You make new commits, and that adds new versions.  The commits *are* the history.<sup>1</sup>

The commits (and the other internal objects) all have *hash IDs*.  The hash ID of any given commit is *totally unique*, across *every Git repository*.  This means that two different clones (or any two repositories, in fact) can easily tell where they diverge from some other clone: the commits they *share*, or have in common, always have the *same* hash ID.  For commits they *don't* share, one Git will find some hash ID `a123456...` or whatever, and the other Git won't find *any object at all* with that hash ID.

What this means for you, a person using Git, is that the hash ID *is* the commit, in a very real and important sense.  But the problem with hash IDs is: they're huge and ugly and no *human* can use them directly.  So we don't: we use *branch names* to find commits.  That's where the second database comes in.

---

<sup>1</sup>This history cannot actually be *changed*.  When you see people talk about "rewriting history", what they mean is that you've *added new history*, and the new history doesn't refer back to the old commits—the existing history.  Normally, you add new history that *does* refer back to the old history.  What you *can and do change* in a pair of Git repository databases are the values stored in the *names*.  If name `main` lets you find commit `a123456` today, and commit `b789abc` tomorrow, then "history" is the set of commits you can find by starting at `a123456` today, and the set of commits you can find by starting at `b789abc` tomorrow.  Normally, we arrange for `b789abc` to refer back to `a123456`; to "rewrite history", we copy as much original history as needed to new-and-improved commits, add any other new-only commits we like, and make `b789abc` refer back to the new history instead of the old history.

The old history doesn't *go away*, at this point.  You just can't *see* it any more.  Eventually, Git will get around to cleaning out these completely-invisible commits, provided that (a) they *are* completely invisible and (b) you don't go back and change your mind and make them visible again.

---

#### Branch names find commits

Branch names, unlike commits, *aren't* unique.  You might have a `main` or `master` in your Git repository, and I might have one in mine, and these two names will hold *different* commit hash IDs.  That's potentially true for *any* name, including tag names, but if our two repositories are *clones*, we *should* store the same hash IDs in our tag names.  (To do otherwise is perfectly *possible*, but leads to insanity, or at least, confusion.  Don't do that.)

Because the definition of a *branch* name is that it holds the hash ID of the *latest* commit, though, we *expect* the branch names in different clones to vary over time.  Every time you check out some branch and make some new commit(s), you're updating *your* branch name's hash ID.  The hash ID finds the *latest* commit.  The latest commit has what every commit has:

- A commit holds a snapshot of all the source files, like a tar or rar or winzip archive.  (However, the *format* of the contained files is weird and Git-specific, with the files literally being shared / re-used within and across commits.  This means if you make a new commit where only one file is *changed*, Git *re-uses* all the files except the one changed one, in the new snapshot, which therefore takes almost no space.)
- A commit holds *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance.  It includes some date-and-time-stamps.  And, so that history works in Git, it includes a list of hash IDs of *previous* commits.

Most commits record exactly one previous commit hash ID here, in their metadata.  This produces a simple backwards-looking chain of commits: that's the history in this branch.  The *branch name* provides the raw hash ID of the *latest* commit.  That *latest* commit provides the snapshot of all files, plus the hash ID of the *second-latest commit*.  That second-latest commit provide the snapshot of all files, plus the hash ID of the third-latest commit, which has a snapshot and metadata giving the hash ID of the fourth-latest commit, which has a snapshot and metadata ... well, you probably get the picture now:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--main
```

If `main` is our branch name and the hash ID it holds is some big ugly random-looking string that we just call `H` for short, then the name `main` *points to* commit `H`.  Commit `H`, in its metadata, stores the hash ID of—i.e., *points to*—earlier commit `G`.  Commit `G` stores the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.

That's the history in the repository.  We use the branch names to find the *latest* commits and then Git works backwards for us.  That's *all there is*, but that's *all we need*.

#### Merging

When we have several branches with both common and their own history, like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

we can ask Git to *merge* commits `J` and `L`, by doing:

```
git switch br1 && git merge br2
```

That is, we start by selecting commit `J` as our *current commit*, and branch name `br1` as our *current branch*.  Then we tell Git: *Using the name `b2`, find the commit, and merge.*  That name locates commit `L` right now, so Git uses commits `J` and `L` to figure out when—at which commit—the branches *were* in sync *before*, and does some simple and stupid text-oriented things to combine the *work done* in the two branches.

The result of this combining-work is a *new snapshot*.  This new snapshot goes into a *new commit*, which we'll call `M` here.  The new commit goes onto the *current branch* in the usual way: the new commit stores, in its metadata, the hash ID of the *current* commit so that `M` points back to `J`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \
          K--L
```

What's special about merge commit `M` is that in its metadata, it lists *two* commit hash IDs instead of just one.  The *second* hash ID in the list is that of the commit we merged in, i.e., commit `L`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

The *branch name* that Git updates, in our repository, is `br1`, because that's the branch name we gave to `git checkout` or `git switch` before we ran `git merge`.  The name `HEAD` in parentheses, attached to one of the branch names, is a way to show the *current branch name*.  The *current commit* is the one the current branch name points-to.  So now that we've made new commit `M`, Git has updated `br1` so that `M` is now the latest commit on branch `br1`.

Because `M` points backwards to *both* `J` *and* `L`, *all* the commits are now on branch `br1`.  Because `br2` points to `L`, and working backwards from `L` does not find commits `M`, `I`, or `J`, there are three commits on `br1` that are not on `br2`, at this point.

#### Remotes and remote-tracking names

Git is not merely a *version control system* or VCS, but is a *distributed* VCS.  In Git's case, this is implemented via *clones*.  We clone a repository, and when we do, we get all of the other repository's *commits*, and *none of its branches*.

That is, suppose some *other* repository has a `main` and a `develop`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

We run `git clone url`.  Our Git:

- saves away the URL, under a name Git calls a *remote;*
- creates a new, totally-empty repository: both databases are empty;
- connects to whoever responds to the given URL: that should be some Git software, connected to a Git repository, and we'll call that combination *their Git;*
- obtains from their Git a list of all their branch names and the corresponding commit hash IDs;
- uses those hash IDs to *get* those commits from them, including their history (all earlier commits);
- takes all their *branch* names and *renames them*, and creates in *our* repository the *renamed* names.

To build the new names, our Git software takes their branch names and sticks the remote's name in front.  The standard first remote name is `origin`.  So the remote, `origin`, does two things for us:

- it saves the URL, so that we can contact their Git again any time in the future; and
- it provides the *remote-tracking names* prefix: their `main` becomes our `origin/main`, and their `develop` becomes our `origin/develop`.

These remote-tracking names function like branch names—they find the *latest* commit—but they are not actually *branch* names.  We cannot `git switch` to them.  So now we have this, in our repository:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

But our own Git software *wants*, in some sense, to be "on a branch".  To be on a branch, our Git must now *create* one *branch* name.  What branch name will our Git create?  The answer comes in two parts:

1. Our Git will create the branch name we told it to, on the command line, using the `-b` option.
2. If we didn't use `-b`—and we didn't—our Git asks their Git which name *they* recommend.  That could be either `main` or `develop` here, since those are the two branch names they have.  It's pretty typical for them to recommend `main`.

So, with all that in mind, our Git probably creates `main` now.  Which *commit* will our name `main` point-to?  The answer is: the same commit *their* name points to, right now, which we've stored locally with the name `origin/main`.  So we get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

Note that we now have *two* names pointing to commit `H`.  That's fine!  A commit can have as many names as you want.  Each name is either a *branch* name, like `main` here, or some other kind of name, like the remote-tracking names here.  *Branch* names are the ones we can give to `git switch`, to get "on" the branch, after which any *new* commits we make will advance the branch name to point to the new commit, which will point back to whatever commit *was* the latest, at that time.  So if we stick with `main` and make a new commit, we get:

```
             K   <-- main (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

#### Merging locally vs `git pull`

To do a purely local merge, we:

- switch to some branch by name, then
- run `git merge` and give the merge command a branch name *or* any other way to find *any commit*.

As long as the other commit is something Git can merge, Git will do the merge (or not—`git merge` has options to make it do something other than a regular merge, for instance, and has some default actions that don't always merge—but we'll assume here that we get a real merge).  The new merge *commit* is a *commit*, so it has a snapshot and metadata.  The metadata include a *log message*.

When you run `git merge` and Git makes a new merge, Git will, by default, open your editor on a file with a *merge message*.  The merge message is where you tell people *why* you did this `git merge` command.  Most people don't bother, though.  They just let Git use its crappy default merge message.  **That default merge message is:**

```
Merge branch 'develop'
```

or:

```
Merge branch 'develop' into feature/tmp
```

The name on the left and in single quotes, `'develop'` in this case, is the name we gave to the `git merge` command.  The `into feature/tmp` part appears when we're *on* a branch named `feature/tmp`; the `into` part appears by default if we're not on the *main* branch, whatever that is (`master` or `main`, now configurable; in older versions of Git, `master` was the only one that got omitted like this).

**This default message is not very good.**  The reason it's so blah is that branch names *change* over time, to point to new commits.  If you're feeling extra-energetic, you might change it to, e.g.:

```
Merge Bob's update to incorporate the new foobler software,
because our feature development needs to foo some bars.
```

In practice, however, nobody seems to bother, as I said earlier.  (You, or whoever made this merge, apparently didn't bother either.)

Now, that's what happens if you run `git merge develop` when you're on your `feature/tmp`.  But what if you run:

```
git pull origin develop
```

?  In this case you're using the `git pull` convenience command.  This command is short for running two Git commands:

1. `git fetch`; then
2. a command of your choice, that you'd normally configure once and then use from now on.

The *default* command in step 2 is `git merge`.  That seems to be your setup: the default, i.e., you never configured `git pull` to run something different.  (Some groups prefer to rebase instead of merge, but that's a personal preference thing: there are valid arguments for preferring rebase, and valid arguments for preferring merge.  Git defaults to merge, which is at least *simpler* than rebase.)

Whenever you run `git fetch`—either directly, or via `git pull`—your Git reaches out to the other Git (the software that responds at the saved URL, using the repository indicated by the saved URL).  Your Git gets, from their Git, any *new commits* they have that you don't, that you'll need.<sup>2</sup>  Your Git then updates your `origin/develop` in your own repository.<sup>3</sup>  So if you had, say:

```
       J--K   <-- feature/tmp (HEAD)
      /
...--H   <-- main
      \
       I   <-- origin/develop
```

before the `git fetch` step, and:

```
       J--K   <-- feature/tmp (HEAD)
      /
...--H   <-- main
      \
       I--L   <-- origin/develop
```

after the `git fetch` step of `git pull`, that means they added one commit—the one we're calling `L` here—to *their* repository since your last `git fetch`.  You now have that commit in *your* repository too, and your `origin/develop` now points to that particular commit.

Your Git software now runs command-number-two, to complete the `git pull`.  That second command in this case is `git merge`, so your Git does a regular merge, which produces a new merge commit `M`:

```
       J--K
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- feature/tmp (HEAD)
      \    /
       I--L   <-- origin/develop
```

(I stopped drawing in the name `main`, but it's still there, pointing to commit `H`: it's just too hard to draw now).

**New merge commit `M` has a log message in its metadata.**  As with a `git merge` command you might run personally, Git normally gives you a chance to *edit* this log message and put in something better, but Git provides a crappy default.  The default comes not from `git merge`, though, but this time from `git pull`.  The `git pull` command *knows* that you just got the *latest* `develop` from the URL stored via the name `origin`.  So your `git pull` generates, as its default fairly-crappy log message:

```
Merge branch 'develop' of <url> into feature/tmp
```

The `<url>` part is the one from `origin`; the `develop` is the argument you gave *to* `git pull`—that is, the commit *their* Git's `develop` identified, as transferred over via `git fetch`—and the `into` part is as usual added if you're not on your main branch, which you're not.

You—or whoever did this merge—accepted this not-so-great default commit message (as most people mostly do), so that's how you got it.

---

<sup>2</sup>When you run `git fetch` with no arguments at all, your Git gets from their Git *all of their branches* and creates or updates *all* your remote-tracking names in the usual way.  You can tell `git fetch` to *limit what it fetches* to that needed for *one* branch, and `git pull` will sometimes do this.  In this particular case, `git pull origin develop` instructs `git fetch` to bring over their new `develop` commits, and then updates only your own `origin/develop`.

<sup>3</sup>Git versions predating Git 1.8.4 fail to update remote-tracking names in these limited-fetch cases.  To fix that, make sure you're not using an ancient version of Git.

---

#### The bottom line

Whoever made one merge locally by running `git merge` let Git use its default merge message.

Whoever made one merge locally by running `git pull` let Git use its default merge message.

Since branch names are always evolving, neither message has much value.  The `pull` message does tell you that whoever did it was using that particular GitHub clone as the source for the commits they merged.  Whether that information has *any* value at all is probably only answerable on an individual basis.